# Run a macro when a checkbox is checked and revert sheet to original state when unchecked

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I am trying to create a checkbox that inserts pre-calculated data into a table when a checkbox is "checked" and reverts the spreadsheet to the state before the checkbox was clicked, when "unchecked".

An example code I have so far is

```vb
Sub XrayWeld()
'
' XrayWeld Macro
'

'
    Range("O7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
      "=((RC[-6]*'Table Data'!R[1]C[-8])+(RC[-5]*'Table Data'!R[1]C[-6])+(RC[-4]*'Table Data'!R[1]C[-5])+(RC[-3]*'Table Data'!R[1]C[-4])+(RC[-2]*'Table Data'!R[1]C[-2])+(RC[-1]*'Table Data'!R[1]C[-1]))"
    Range("O7").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("O7:O30"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("O7:O30").Select
    Sheets("Calculator Form ").Select
    Range("O32").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: use a separate worksheet tucked away in the box to hold the state of the cells before the checkbox was checked. Use Event handlers to copy the data to this worksheet and update with new values when the box is checked, and when its unchecked, bring the values from the worksheet back to the original state.

Comment: So the event handlers would be on the seperate data sheet? Or on the one that is being updated? I am very new to coding and am basically trying to self teach myself

Comment: the event handlers will be associated with the checkbox. So you essentially run a macro that checks the state of the check box when it's clicked (True = Checked, False = Not Checked), then take action accordingly with the rest of the macro. See [this](http://wellsr.com/vba/2015/excel/complete-guide-to-excel-vba-ActiveX-checkboxes/) for more help with that.